# A web element is clicked but no action is performed (Android)

Tags: java, android, click, driver

desculpa pelo idioma, mas assim serei mais direto

estou com um problema, eu encontro o elemento (mobile) em um device real, aponto para ele e clico, mas sempre retorna a mensagem de erro ‘java.lang.NullPointerException’, alguém pode me ajudar? Codigo abaixo

```
public class testCalculator {
    @Test
    public void teste() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "DACEE6CE5DCEEQEI");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.calculator");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.calculator.Calculator");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
        AndroidDriver<?> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.calculator:id/tips_btn")).click();
        //driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.tct.calculator:id/tips_btn\").instance(0)")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você sabe dizer em qual linha está dando o Exception?